# What's the effect of a standard bullet hitting Earth at 0.99 c?

Tags: apocalypse, weapon-mass-destruction

Let's say that some aliens got mad at us and decided to destroy Earth. A young child on one of the alien starships was playing with his toy gun which could shoot normal bullets at relativistic speeds...

The bullet is a standard one, let's say for the sake of simplicity one that is used on a AK47. It is shot towards Earth at 0.99 c.

What would be the effects of the impact? I imagine the bullet doesn't have enough time to burn up in the atmosphere. Do the effects vary by impact angle?

Comment: This: [Diamond](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/). Or this: [Relativistic baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/).

Comment: Assuming it doesn't simply fall apart first, of course.

Comment: Voting to close: this is not a world building question. It's more of a Physics question.

Comment: We also have several "How to destroy the planet" questions that pretty much cover this as well.  Mainly this answer http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/18419/189

Comment: possible duplicate of [What single element could destroy the world?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18414/what-single-element-could-destroy-the-world)

Comment: it's very similar to this one http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/the-last-ride-of-the-magic-schoolbus-termination-of-the-ignorant.  The formula used there can be used to estimate the effects of a bullet sized projectile vs. a school bus sized one.